# pay for app through PayPal before you can use it.

Tags: android

I have this android icon pack I made and published on Amazon app store,  but want to add it to Google playstore. The problem is that I can't sell apps on playstore but only give them for free because I can't have a merchant account in RSA.

Now my question to you is,  is there a way I can implement something that you pay through PayPal after you downloaded the app and before you can use it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put it in the play store no there is not because it is against the developer agreement for in-app purchases. you must use google's in-app purchases if you want to enable stuff after download or else risk getting the app pulled.